# patch command can't create the new file

Tags: command-line, patch

I was testing the patch command and created 2 dirs like this:

```
d1:

d2:
file1.txt
```

I used diff to create a patchfile and patched it:

```
diff -Naur d1 d2 > patchfile.txt
patch -p0 <patchfile.txt
```

but it didn't create the d1/file1.txt and shows me this message:

```
The next patch would create the file d2/file1.txt,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

I couldn't figure out the problem, please help me with that.

patchfile.txt:

```
--- d1/file1.txt    1969-12-31 19:00:00.000000000 -0500
+++ d2/file1.txt    2017-11-12 22:48:07.428873802 -0500
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+a
+b
+c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
diff -Naur d1 d2 > patchfile.txt
patch -p0 <patchfile.txt
```

... did you mean:

```
cd d1; patch -p1 < ../patchfile.txt
```

After all, the patch file contains changes that have happened (new file in `d2`). There's no point in telling it to do what's already been done, is there?

Comment: Yes, "cd d1; patch -p1 < ../patchfile.txt" work, but why "patch -p0 <patchfile.txt" doesn't work, it should be the same thing.

Comment: And what do you mean there's no point in telling it to do what's already been done. The purpose is to make d1(old-version) same as d2(new-version)

Comment: @void7 have you read the patch?

Comment: You mean patchfile.txt?

Comment: so why doesn't `patch -p0` turn file d1/file1.txt into d2/file2.txt? Does it ignore the prefix?

Comment: @qwr it doesn't exactly ignore the prefix. The exact algorithm is probably described in the manual somewhere, but GNU patch prefers, among other things, the file path that results in the creation of the fewest entities (directories, files, etc.). If you do `rm d2/file.txt` so that both directories are now the same, and then apply the patch, it will then pick the first of the paths in the header.